# Startactivityforresult() and Don't keep Activity option in phone settings

Tags: android, start-activity

I have came across a weird experience and so far i couldn't find a solution for this and hope someone here can help me..The Issue is, I have 2 activities(say Activity A and Activity B) and i started Activity B from Activty A using StartActivityForResult() and before that i have checked "Don't keep activity option" in phone settings and when i finish the ACtivity B the app is crashing , I know this is happening because i have checked that option in settings but i want to know how i can overcome this issue , What is the best and android recommended way for fixing this?

Comment: I want a solution if i check this option

Comment: yes, that i want to know

Comment: What use case are you trying to support with that? The previous activity being not available when your app is in the foreground is the rarest of rare use case.